# Manipulation of global variable in C

Tags: c, global-variables

I have a lot of global variables whose name is very long, e.g:

```
var1.var2.var3.var4.myGlobalVar1[N]
```

And I must use this variables in my function. 
My question is what is the best way to manipulate this variable? is it necessary to do a copy into a local variable to increase the readability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to increase readability is indeed to create a local variable. This local variable will get optimized away in the final executable, so it won't affect the program's performance. The local variable can either be a hard copy of the struct member, or a pointer to it, depending on what's most convenient from case to case.

You can also use macros in various ways, but I don't recommend it, since they clutter down the global namespace.

---

If you still insist in using macros for whatever reason, then you should do like this:

```
#define SHORT var1.var2.var3.var4.myGlobalVar1
...
SHORT[i] = something;
```

You should *not* use function-like macros in this case. They aren't type safe, they are hard to read, hard to debug and hard to maintain. Macros in general are dangerous and bad practice.

Comment: The global variable is an array, so depending on your answer i think that the best way is to create a local variable which point to it. is it true?

Comment: @physics Most likely that's the best idea, yes.

Answer (score 4):

if you only want to increase the readability, you can use

```
#define SHORTER_NAME var1.var2.var3.var4.myGlobalVar1[N]
```

if it is an array you can use

```
#define SHORTER_NAME var1.var2.var3.var4.myGlobalVar1
```

to access each value with `SHORTER_NAME[index]`